# Can we have a question's tags be displayed at the top in all review queues and tabs?

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, review

When reviewing items, I often find myself switching tabs, between e.g. 'Answer' and 'Question', not in the least because to properly assess the quality of i.c. an answer, I need to know what the question is specifically about. Tags (when properly applied) go a long way to quickly get an idea of the intent of a question.

By copy/pasting the [div with the class `post-taglist`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EhW4.png) to in-between the tabs and the item's body we can go from this..

[image]

..to this..

[image]

..and this will immediately give a clearer picture of what aspects to focus on.

Switching tabs is certainly not a big deal, and is probably going to be necessary in many cases anyway, but this way the tags will remain in the same position when switching tabs, and it saves having to scroll down the body of a post (of unknown length) just to look at the tags (again).

Comment: It should be a little higher, directly under the title of the question.